# How do I restore a single file with Deja Dup / Nautilus 3.8?

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, backup, deja-dup

All tutorials say I have to go to the "File" menu and hit some sort of restore button, which does not consider that this freaking new file manager does not even have a menu bar. How am I supposed to reach this option? Also, there's nothing fitting in the context menu or the options menu on the right side of the Nautilus panel.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line:

```
deja-dup --restore path/to/file.whatever
```

It'll take ages to scan through the archives, but it'll restore only that file eventually.

Answer (score -1):

Try right clicking.  You should get a menu option to revert the file.

Comment: As I wrote, there is nothing in the context menu. I don't want to revert a file, but restore a deleted file that should exist in the backup.

Comment: Right clicking on what? Why are you talking about reverting when the question asks about restoring a file?